# "Next" Button in Javascript & used JavascriptExecutor to click on "next" button but it does not help me out

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

This is the inspect element.

```
<script language="javascript"> 
<input type="submit" onclick="return processPIData(this);hideThisButton()" value=" Next "> <input type="reset" value="Reset ">
```

And my script is :

```
JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

jsExecutor.executeScript("document.getElementByTagName('input')[0].click()");
```

but this was not working.

Comment: your html is invalid. you should consider learning html and javascript.

Comment: please guide me how write webdriver code for clicking that Next button

Answer (score 0):

Your Javascript is wrong, it should be:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].click();
```

Although I'm not entirely sure why you are needing to use Javascript for this. Builtin selector methods should work fine.

Comment: Hi Arran , tried with same as above  even its not working ( its not clicking on Next button)

Comment: What language are you using? What version of Selenium? What browser? Have you tried using XPath?

Comment: Arran ,i am using java , selenium-2.25.0, Mozila 

no haven't try with Xpath

Comment: What version of Firefox? Have you tried updating to the latest version of Selenium?

Comment: Mozila Version shows like :17.0.1,

i think selenium-2.25.0 its latest version ,if  wrong please correct me.

Comment: No, it's very out of date. It's just the website hasn't been updated. Download v2.28 direct from their SVN repository: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list  ...Firefox v17 isn't supported until this version of Selenium, so it's probably your issue.

Comment: I am updating Selenium latest version then i will try with same code ,Thanks for the information Arran :)

Comment: Hi Arran , updated with latest version, even that too does not help me out.

Comment: Can it click the 2nd input button? If you change the `[0]` to `[1]`, does it click the button?